# Notification's contrast color is wrong in Android 12. How to fix this?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-theme, android-12

To make my notification attached to a foreground service stand out, I've been setting the color of a notification. On Android 11 and below, the system automatically sets the colors of the buttons according to the color. However, on Android 12, regardless of what color I use, the texts, the buttons, titles etc all remain dark. So how can I set the theme to be dark so the buttons become white?

This is my notification builder code -

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MaplocsNotificationChannels.FOLLOW_LOCATION.channelId)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification, getString(R.string.generic_word_show),
                activityPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification, getString(R.string.navigation_mode_stop),
                servicePendingIntent)
        .setContentText(
                navigationStep?.getFormattedDistanceText(this)
                        ?: getString(R.string.navigation_mode_notification_message))
        .setContentTitle(navigationStep?.instruction
                ?: getString(R.string.generic_word_navigate_route))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primaryColor))
        .setColorized(true)
        .setSilent(true)
        .setContentIntent(activityPendingIntent)
        .setLargeIcon(
                if (navigationStep != null)
                    getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(navigationStep.getIconId()).apply {
                        changeColor(Color.WHITE)
                    }
                else null
        )
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .build()
```

On Android 11 and below, system automatically changes button colors based on notification color `builder.setColor()`-
[image]
[image]

However, on Android 12, the button, text colors remain the same regardless of the notification color -
[image]
[image]

How can I set the theme for notifications on Android 12?

---

**Edit (1)** - As pointed out by @Pawel, the reason why this is happening is because the contract calculation has changed on Android 12. If I set the color to `#424242`, a much darker color, then the text becomes white. Now the only question is, how to do this manually?

[image]

---

**Edit (2)** - I dug into the Android source code and found the source of the issue. The main logic for calculating the contrast is in the `ContrastColorUtil.java` class. If the notification is colorised (i.e. it has a non-default background color), the `Notification.Builder()` class calls the `shouldUseDark()` method. This method determines based on the background color whether the notification should use dark colors or light colors on the notification elements. In Android 12, this is the method definition -

```
public static boolean shouldUseDark(int backgroundColor, boolean defaultBackgroundIsDark) {
    if (backgroundColor == COLOR_DEFAULT) {
        return !defaultBackgroundIsDark;
    }
    // Color contrast ratio luminance midpoint, X: 1.05 / (X + 0.05) = (X + 0.05) / 0.05
    // Solved as X = sqrt(.05 * 1.05) - 0.05 = 0.17912878474
    return calculateLuminance(backgroundColor) > 0.17912878474;
}
```

I don't understand the logic behind calculating the luminanace value of a color, but the constant value which is supposed to be a mid-value was changed from `0.5` to `0.17912878474` in Android 12. This is the source of the error. The change was made in this commit -

https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/cab7d8e0116066ad5f1d00e6a47ad1a65bf6dd80

Since this code cant be changed, and since there is no public method to set the notification theme, the only solution I see to fixing this issue is using reflection to manipulate the private internal value in the Notification instance. The problem with doing that is that most of the notification's values are set in the Notification.Builder() methods so we would have to change many elements (title, message, icon color, button colors, etc) in the notification to fix it completely.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it keep text black even if you use really dark colors? Maybe only contrast calculation changed

Comment: @Pawel That was an excellent point. You are right, the contrast calculation has indeed changed. When I set the color to #424242, the notification text became white. Now the only question is, how to do this manually?

Comment: You could probably find it if you dive into AOSP source code. But I'd still recommend using an icon with actual background because even if you manage to align the color on stock android you can't really tell what's going to happen on third party implementations.

Comment: @Pawel I dug into the AOSP source and did find the issue source. I've added the details as an edit to the question. Regarding the icon, the notification design spec does not allow adding a colorised icon. The coloring is done by the notification logic itself based on the primary color. However, the icon is just one of the elements - the title, message, button colors are all whose color needs to be fixed.